# fb_screenshot.png is not the one of my web

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I updated the image of fb_screenshot.png of my website (www.fb.com/uingaming) and facebook keeps shwoing another one (the previous) when sending the URL on a message or post.

When using the facebook debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.uingaming.com

The image is correct, but when I insert www.uingaming.com on a message it appears like this:

http://postimg.org/image/etxq3axxp/19793d67/

Comment: I cleared cache and lowered the resolutions of the image and it is not working. I erased fb_screenshot.png from ftp and it keeps showing the same image. I guess i need to change the url the image as lgy says but i dont know where. Its a wordpress template

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser's cache and see if that works. Or may be test it in some other browser just to be sure that it is cache problem.

Update: Your new image http://uingaming.com/wp-content/themes/afternight/fb_screenshot.png is taking too long to respond. May be this is the reason. Fix this first.

Comment: Also, you need to change the URL of the image